# Cropping the SSIS Designer view

Tags: ssis

In a SQL Server Integration Services project, the designer view has created a large amount of unused space above the space I'm actually using. **Notice the size of the right scrollbar in the following zoomed out view.**

[image: SSIS Image with extra whitespace]

When starting the project, the designer's view always starts in the upper left corner, meaning I have to scroll to the bottom to see any of my work. **Is there any way to clip the designer's working space to what I'm actually using?** I've verified there is absolutely nothing above the containers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the Fit to Window view (the square-ish box at the bottom of the slider). Then select all your tasks. Drag all of them together to the left-top corner. After sometime, enlarge the view to 100% (the dark line on the slider). Do it couple times till you have what you want.

Comment: Moving everything to the top left corner works great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. Yes, it's quite different from what we had in earlier versions. I had spoken with one of the most renowned SSIS developer from Microsoft in last october who agreed that it was done hurriedly and needs improvement as the user-experience is not up to the mark. Hope they do...

Answer (score 2):

`Format -> Auto Layout -> Diagram`

This will Auto size your boxes and bring them back to top left. Doing it manually is annoying and almost impossible.

[image: SSIS Visual Studio Scrrenshot]

Comment: This worked for me. Just one catch: annotations seem always to end up at the bottom of the diagram. Serves us right for wanting to document our flows, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Select all controls and cut it. Click Fit View on Windows bottom right corner. It will resize. Then paste your control back.